# How to make labels look good after being reprojected in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, tileserver-gl

I am using OpenLayers with tileserver-gl and using raster reprojection to display the map with a conical projection. I have the following layer in my styles.json file:

```
{
      "id": "city",
      "type": "symbol",
      "source": "openmaptiles",
      "source-layer": "place",
      "filter": ["all", ["in", "class", "city", "town"]],
      "layout": {
        "text-field": { "type": "identity", "property": "name:latin" },
        "text-justify": "center",
        "text-anchor": "center",
        "text-writing-mode": [],
        "text-keep-upright": false,
        "text-transform": "uppercase",
        "text-optional": false,
        "text-size": 18
      },
      "paint": {
        "text-halo-width": 1,
        "text-halo-color": "rgba(15, 15 ,15, 1)",
        "text-color": "rgba(125, 125, 125, 1)"
      }
    }
```

And the text formatting seems to be getting effected by the reprojection (Click on screenshot below for full sized image to observe the effect. Left side is using reprojection, right is not)
[image]

You can see that the text on the left side darker, blurry and not parallel to the screen.

I would like the text on the left to look like the text on right. Is there any clever way to achieve this with the styles file? If not, what is the common approach for solving this?

Comment: With raster data, the labels are embedded as an image (in the projection the image was created in).  Reprojecting the raster will warp the image, including the labels.  The only solution to this is to reproject the original source (vector) data instead of reprojecting the raster data.  You can then regenerate raster data in the final projection.  Of course, this only works if you have access to the source vector data.

Comment: Blurring might be reduced slightly if you use the tileserver-gl `@2x` or `@4x` options (and specify the `tilePixelRatio` in the OpenLayers source options), but the labels will always be aligned with the source projection.